# Determining a formula for tiling an $n \times n$ board with $1 \times 1$ and $2 \times 2$ tiles

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $T_n$ denote the number of ways tiling an $n \times n$ with $1 \times 1$ and $2 \times 2$ tiles (rotations of configurations are considered distinct). Construct a bound or a formula for $T_n$.

This question seems to have a lot of complexity involved. I attempted to create a recursion between consecutive $n$ and even and odd $n$, without success, as a result of the freedom given to the tiles.

I created an easy bound $T_{2n} \geq 2^{n^2}$ and $T_{2n+1} \geq 4 \times (T_{2n} - 1) + 1 \geq 2^{n^2+2} - 3$ for $n \geq 1$. This was by assuming a structure the $2 \times 2$ tiles followed, but this structure could just as easily not exist.

How could I go about solving this problem?

Comment: A typical approach is compute first few terms using whatever method, throw the results to OEIS and see what one get. I computed first 10 terms using transfer matrix and an OEIS search return [OEIS A063443](https://oeis.org/A063443). Look at refs there for more detail. According to a formula there, $\lim_{n\to\infty} T_n^{1/n^2}$ converges to some number $\approx 1.342643951124$.